# dividing polynomials into separate parts and printing their coefficients and power

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
int isnumber(char *temp) ;
void divide(char array[]);
void divide2(char array[]);
void append(char* s, char c);
int main()
{
    char array[20];
    scanf("%s",array);
    divide2(array);


   return 0;

}
int isnumber(char *temp) {
  int i = 0;
int flag=0 ;
 for (i=0;i<strlen(temp);i++) {
if (!isdigit(temp[i])){
flag = 1;
 }
 else if(temp[0]=='-' && isdigit(temp[i])){
 flag=0;
  }
}
return flag;
}
void divide2( char array[]){
    char array1[20];
    int j=0,i;
    for(i=0 ; i<strlen(array1);i++)
                {
                    array1[i]=NULL;
                }


    for(i=0;i<strlen(array);i++){
            if(array[i]!='+'||array[i]!='-')
            {

                append(array1,array[i]);
                j++;
            }
            else{


                divide(array1);
                for(i=0 ; i<strlen(array1);i++)
                {
                    array1[i]='\0';
                }
            }

    }
}
void divide(char array[]){

    int co,pow,i;
    char *token1;
    char t[20];
   char *t_3[2];



    token1= strtok(array,"+");
    strcpy(t,token1);

   while(token1!=NULL){


t_3[0] = strtok(t,"x^");


t_3[1] = strtok(NULL,"x^");



if((t_3[0] == NULL)&&(t_3[1] == NULL)) {

co = 1;
 pow = 1;
 }
 else if((token1[0]=='-')&& (token1[1]== 'x') && (t_3[1] != NULL)){
    co=-1;
    pow=atoi(t_3[1]);
 }
 else if ((token1[0]=='-') &&(t_3[0] != NULL)&&(t_3[1] != NULL)){
    co=atoi(t_3[0]);
    pow=atoi(t_3[1]);
}

 else if((token1[0]=='-')&& (token1[1]== 'x') && (t_3[1] == NULL)){
    co=-1;
    pow=1;
 }


    else if(isnumber(token1)==0) {
 co = atoi(t);
pow = 0;
}
else if ((t_3[0] != NULL)&&(t_3[1] == NULL) && (token1[0]=='x')){
pow = atoi(t_3[0]);
co= 1;
 }
 else if ((t_3[0] != NULL)&&(t_3[1] == NULL)) {
co = atoi(t_3[0]);
pow = 1;
 }

else {

 co = atoi(t_3[0]);
pow = atoi(t_3[1]);
 }

 printf("coefficient is : %d   power is :%d\n",co,pow);

 co=0;
 pow=0;
 t_3[0]='\0';
 t_3[1]='\0';
for(i=0 ; i<sizeof(t);i++){
        t[i]='\0';
        }
token1 = strtok(NULL,"+");
        if(token1==NULL){
            printf("...............");
            printf("\n");
        }
        else{
        strcat(t,token1);
        }
   }
}

void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}
```

This code is supposed to split polynomials and print their power and coefficient but I keep getting the error `undefined reference` to append. Can any one tell me why? I have tried searching for this error but did not find a solution .
i fixed the problem .. but the function itself won't work

Comment: Your `append` is declared inside of another function due to a missing right brace `}`. You will see this easily if you fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: i fixed it ... but the function won't work

Comment: *won't work* is not very descriptive.

Comment: use a debugger to step through your code

Comment: 0)`i<strlen(array1)` at divide2. change to `i < 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if(array[i]!='+'||array[i]!='-')
```

is always true. You mean (I think)

```
if(array[i]!='+'&& array[i]!='-')
```

Comment: that seemed to be the problem .. but still the last part of the array does not go through the function